# Numerical analysis: least squares method

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, least-squares

Basically I came up with a function where I need to approximate it using the least squares method. I had no trouble computing the constants on MATLAB and got to the following plot:
[image]

Now as you see the curves are approximately the same but not exactly. I'm looking for a rather sharp explanation to this? Is it because the function is very oscillatory? Is it because it constantly oscillates between negative and positive values? Can someone give me some insight about this? I really want to understand what I am obtaining. Thanks!

Comment: I think it could be good you show the function you want to fit as well as the data points. Otherwise, it could be difficult to help you. Cheers.

Comment: I second Claude's suggestion.